# Cocos2d-x Sprite flickers during scale animation sequence

Tags: c++, animation, sprite, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a grow / shrink animation sequence. But for some reason the sprite does not scale smoothly. I did change the animation interval and disabled depth test but it did not fix this.
What can be the reason behind this?
Does does have something to do with art asset that is used?

```
ScaleTo* grow = ScaleTo::create(1, 1.5);
ScaleTo* shrink = ScaleTo::create(1, 1);
Sequence* anim = Sequence::create(grow, shrink , NULL);
 
RepeatForever *rep = RepeatForever::create(anim);

station_image->runAction(rep);
```

---

#### Solved

I was able to fix this issue by enabling ‘CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL’ in ccConfig.h

Comment: what do you mean by smooth scaling ?

Comment: The animation is choppy. One can see artifacts at the edges of the sprite when it scales. Does this have something to do with the resolution of sprite ?